# Android Nougat has different dp calculation? Button sizes changed after update

Tags: android, android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-button, android-7.0-nougat

My Samsung Galaxy s7 just updated to Android Nougat 7.0 and I noticed some of the buttons are displayed differently. I happen to have another Galaxy s7 around which hasn't gone through the update yet (Marshmallow 6.0.1). I can see the difference in sizes very clearly:

Marshmallow:

[image]

Nougat:

[image]

The layout_height of that *SHARE* button is hard set to 44dp. Using Layout Inspector in Android Studio I can read that it resolves to 176px for Marshmallow and 132px for Nougat (same values for mMeasuredHeight). You can also see that the other part of the layout on the left remained the same (ignore the little thumb up icon).

Another example:

Marshmallow:

[image: Marshmallow]

Nougat:

[image]

I'm using following styling for the buttons:

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorTextBrightPrimary</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint" >#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorTextBrightPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Button.Accent" parent="AppTheme.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextBrightPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint" >@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

While the *SHARE* button is a custom view, extending AppCompatButton, the Google and Facebook auth buttons are just AppCompatButtons. In either way, they all looked different just before the update and nothing else was changed in code, nor on the device (text size and zoom are the same).

**Any idea what's going on? How to ensure these layouts stay the same on various devices/OS'?**

Comment: "Using Layout Inspector in Android Studio I can read that it resolves to 176px for Marshmallow and 132px for Nougat (same values for mMeasuredHeight)" -- are there any margins? Did those margins change? Is there any padding on whatever the container is that the SHARE button is inside? Did that padding change? If you look at `Configuration` and `DensityMetrics`, did their reported densities change?

Comment: @CommonsWare No margins in both cases. The container padding equal to 0 in both cases. The button's padding however did change. Nougat 48 40 48 40 and Marshmallow 36 30 36 30 for Left Top Right Bottom respectively. I don't set padding in code anywhere

Comment: OK, perhaps they changed the default padding on a button. That would explain part, though perhaps not all, of the difference. You could try defining padding in your style and see how much that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I made a mistake, it was padding Marshmallow 48/40 and Nougat 36/30 - that doesn't make sense does it? Why the different resolved heights? I tried changing padding yet as expected it furthered the padding even more.

Comment: I went on assuming the default drawable for button may have been changed hence the difference, and so I created my own drawable that I could control padding and size of better. Not an ideal solution, as the ripple doesn't work quite as well as in the original, hence this isn't really an answer to the question. Any ideas or leads in the topic would be great!

Comment: Are you saying that switching the background of the button to your own drawable fixed the sizing problem?

Comment: Yes, now its same on all devices I have, galaxy s3 and the two s7's

Answer (score 0):

A drawable can have its own padding. In the case of a nine-patch PNG file, that's simply having transparent pixels outside of the actual non-transparent/resizing portion of the image. In the case of `ShapeDrawable`, you can directly declare padding in the XML. And so on. This may or may not show up as "padding" in tools like the Layout Inspector, as they focus on padding declared on widgets.

Since the previous background you were using had the problem, and the replacement background does not, my guess is that this sort of implicit padding is the problem.

You have two approaches for trying to deal with this:

- The risky-but-simple approach is to try using negative padding on the button itself, in a `res/values-v24/` variant of your style resources (or, optionally, use a consistent dimension resource in the style and vary the dimension values based on `-v25` or not). You would have to tinker a bit to try to get values that "undo" the change. I call this "risky" as I haven't the foggiest notion how well Android respects negative padding.
- The aggravating approach is to try to find the actual button background that you were using before, and see what changed about it. The drawables would be declared either in `appcompat-v7`'s themes or the platform's themes, and the actual drawables themselves would then be defined either in `appcompat-v7` or in the platform.